# DB Seeder class not found

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-artisan

I am trying to seed a database with the following files, 'ItemsTableSeeder' and 'UsersTableSeeder', but I keep on receiving the message: "Target class [ItemsTableSeeder] does not exist." when I run php artisan db:seed.

The files were added in the command prompt with the commands 'php artisan make:seeder ItemsTableSeeder' and 'php artisan make:seeder UsersTableSeeder'.

Here's the structure of my files:

-database

-- factories

- ItemFactory.php
- UserFactory.php

-- seeders

- DatabaseSeeder.php
- ItemsTableSeeder.php
- UsersTableSeeder.php

// ItemsTableSeeder.php

```
    <?php
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
    
    class ItemsTableSeeder extends Seeder
    {
        /**
         * Run the database seeds.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function run()
        {
            factory(\App\Items::class, 20)->create();
        }
    }
```

// UsersTableSeeder.php

```
    <?php
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
    
    class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
    {
        /**
         * Run the database seeds.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function run()
        {
            factory(\App\Users::class, 3)->create();
        }
    }
```

```
DatabaseSeeder.php

    <?php
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; 
    
    class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
    {
        /**
         * Seed the application's database.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function run()
        {
            $this->call('ItemsTableSeeder');
            $this->call('UsersTableSeeder');
        }
    }
```

I have tried running 'composer dump-autoload' after adding the two seeder files, but at this stage this is not making any difference. I have also tried clearing the cache 'php artisan config:cache'.

Here is an extract from my 'autoload_classmap.php' (after running composer dump-autoload):

```
 'Cron\\HoursField' => $vendorDir . '/dragonmantank/cron-expression/src/Cron/HoursField.php',
    'Cron\\MinutesField' => $vendorDir . '/dragonmantank/cron-expression/src/Cron/MinutesField.php',
    'Cron\\MonthField' => $vendorDir . '/dragonmantank/cron-expression/src/Cron/MonthField.php',
    'Database\\Factories\\ItemFactory' => $baseDir . '/database/factories/ItemFactory.php',
    'Database\\Factories\\UserFactory' => $baseDir . '/database/factories/UserFactory.php',
    'DeepCopy\\DeepCopy' => $vendorDir . '/myclabs/deep-copy/src/DeepCopy/DeepCopy.php',
    'DeepCopy\\Exception\\CloneException' => $vendorDir . '/myclabs/deep-copy/src/DeepCopy/Exception/CloneException.php',
    'DeepCopy\\Exception\\PropertyException' => $vendorDir . '/myclabs/deep-copy/src/DeepCopy/Exception/PropertyException.php',
    'DeepCopy\\Filter\\Doctrine\\DoctrineCollectionFilter' => $vendorDir . '/myclabs/deep-copy/src/DeepCopy/Filter/Doctrine/DoctrineCollectionFilter.php',
    'DeepCopy\\Filter\\Doctrine\\DoctrineEmptyCollectionFilter' => $vendorDir . '/myclabs/deep-copy/src/DeepCopy/Filter/Doctrine/DoctrineEmptyCollectionFilter.php',
    'DeepCopy\\Filter\\Doctrine\\DoctrineProxyFilter' => $vendorDir . '/myclabs/deep-copy/src/DeepCopy/Filter/Doctrine/DoctrineProxyFilter.php',
```

Any ideas of other things to try would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks,

Robert

London, England

Comment: make sure "database/seeds" is present in the "classmap" under "autoload" key of your composer.json file

Comment: What happens if you run php artisan db:seed --class=ItemsTableSeeder?

Comment: @Flo Espen I get exactly the same message. And yes database/seeders is present in the classmap folder
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },

Comment: Any further ideas here? Still not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

add `namespace Database\Seeders;` at top of each seeder files

Then composer dump-autoload

Answer (score 0):

Your structure files working good.

Try to fresh migrite
php artisan migrate:fresh --seed

if still not fixed try this: php artisan db:seed --force

then:
1- composer dump-autoload
2- php artisan db:seed

let me know if that work

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried add `namespace Database\Seeders;` before run command?

Comment: Yes. Robert you missing namespace, that's why causing error.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you forget to import Users model.
For example:
database\seeders\UsersSeeder.php

```
namespace Database\Seeders;

use App\Models\Users;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).